# how to create Responsive navbar like http://jacksbarlondon.co.uk/

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I need no build a responsive mobile navbar like http://jacksbarlondon.co.uk/
in this http://jacksbarlondon.co.uk/ site mobile version while i clicked on navbar icon a pop up is coming . how to make a pop up similar to this sit?
please help

Comment: look up media queries. We're not going to write the code for you. Give us at least your attempt.

Comment: Maybe use a framework, like Bootstrap, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick pure css solution. Hope it helps. 
You will need to customize it to suit more to your needs.

```css
.mobile-menu > .trigger:focus + ul {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(47, 55, 59, 0.8);
}
.trigger {
  background: rgba(47, 55, 59, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.navigation-mobile {
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 0.4s ease;
  transition: 0.4s ease;
  list-style: none;
}
.navigation-mobile a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 2;
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="mobile-menu">
  <a href="#" class="trigger"> &#9776;</a>
  <ul class="navigation-mobile">
    <li>
      <a href="#">Demo 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Demo 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Demo 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```